# How do I insert data into a table (and return it) when a select statement outputs no rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql table that is created like this;

```
CREATE TABLE test_contacts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    databit int NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_contacts_name_uindex ON test_contacts (name);
```

When I want to retrieve data i do `SELECT * FROM test_contacts WHERE name = '{name}';`

In my current java application I am doing the following: (pseudocode)

```
Object result = SELECT * FROM test_contacts WHERE name = '{name}';
if (result == null) {  
   INSERT INTO test_contacts (`name`, `databit`) VALUES ('{name}', 2);
   result = SELECT * FROM test_contacts WHERE name = '{name}';
}
```

Is there a way to compact these 3 database calls into 1 statement that always returns a row for the specified name? (I need the `id` that is inserted)

Comment: If you are `inserting`, then why are you doing `select` again? Do you not know all the `*` that is going to come from `select` now(except `id` of course) ?

Comment: Maybe i needed to clarify that i indeed need the id too

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @Jordie Any reason for combining them into one? Does 3 database calls consume a lot of time?

Comment: It seems more convenient to me to turn it into one statement, rather than adding the functionality to my application like i am doing now

Comment: In MySQL, there is no way to combine a `SELECT` and `INSERT` into one row.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a unique index anyway, instead of checking in your code, if your first select had any result, you simply do

```
INSERT IGNORE test_contacts (`name`, `databit`) VALUES ('{name}', 2);
```

- read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

Then you get the `id` with

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

- read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: If i do the following in order; 
`INSERT IGNORE test_contacts (name, databit) VALUES ('noa', 2);`
`SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Using this data; https://gyazo.com/f6d1bb123a86089b4d8ef4e58f841e14
i will still get the id of `lisa` since its the last entry i inserted

Comment: Well, yes, that's what is also said in the manual I linked. It's also stated there, that it works on a per-connection basis.

Comment: But that is not what i am looking for

Comment: You can't combine an insert and a select in a way that it returns you a value after inserting. What else are you looking for?

Comment: Nothing, this was exactly the answer i was looking for